# weird log4net reference error on initial load after deployment

Tags: asp.net, log4net

I am getting the attached error, ever since I put the latest version of log4net (1.2.11.0) on my solution projects.
This happens on server right after I deploy, and when I refresh again it just disappears until next deployment. Please notice that I've tried the following version redirection code, but it did not help:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.10.0" newVersion="1.2.11.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

This is the error I am getting:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

```
 Line 76:     </script>
Line 77:     <form id="form1" runat="server">
Line 78:     <asp:ScriptManager ID="radscriptmanager" runat="server">
Line 79:     </asp:ScriptManager>
Line 80:     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphAfterScriptManager" runat="server">
```

Source File: MainFront.Master    Line: 78

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' could not be loaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect the reason for this could be that you've got dependencies on 1.2.10 in your application and the new version you've installed of log4net is not compatible due to the new signing key.

1.2.11 you'll notice has been signed with a different key which has caused pain for many people. I ended up just reverting back to 1.2.10.

However there is a version of 1.2.11 that has carried on with previous key. Just download that and do the following and all should be okay.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="1b44e1d426115821" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.10.0"
                             newVersion="1.2.11.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

You can get the new and old key from the following url: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi

Comment: I've tried using my public key (1b44e1d426115821) with the Old version and the New version and still I get this error.

Comment: I'm assuming you've actually downloaded the different assemblies though rather than just changing the configuration key? As silly as it sounds, has the reference to the log4net assembly exist within your bin directory? Makes me think whether it's been set to copy always.